# Performance of sequential and parallel computing with low cost tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

i have a List of Objects "Cell" which represent a current status.

`List<Cell> currentCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();`

I want to update the current status in a loop by calculating a future status (a new List of Cells) an then do replacing by "current status = future status" and so on. For that every Cell has a method which returns a new Cell Object representing its future. This method has simple math operations. There are no dependencies to other calculations. So, in theory, future Cells could be computet in parallel Threads.

My Problem is to find the fastet way of computing the future status cause the "List cells" is a very large ArrayList(4000000) and i want to reach up to 25 loops /second.

If i compute it sequentially my loop repeats 3 times / second. If i do high parallelisation by making each Cell a callable and putting them in an ExecuterService my loop repeats only with 0.5 per second.

`List<Future<Cell>> futures = taskExecutor.invokeAll(cells);`

I know that solving a problem in parallel always needs an overhead. In this case it speeds down my loop. What method can you recommend to speed up my loop?

Comment: How many threads do you have in ExecutorService?

Comment: Make the number of threads equal to number of processors. You could reach to 12 times/ second if you have 4 cores. Parallel programming isn't magic, you are bound to hardware resources.

Comment: I think we need to see your code to understand 1) what you are doing, and 2) why threads appear to be making it slower.

Comment: I would say you have to measure it, e.g. with a java micro benchmark. You can setup different scenarios, for-each loop, parallel streams, executor and check it.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be no difference in speed anyway if i change numberOfThreads from 1 up to 12 (i have maximum of 12 processors). The code of my loop is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import view.ConsolePrinter;

public class Engine implements Runnable {

    private int numberOfThreads = 8;
    private boolean shouldRun = false;
    private ExecutorService taskExecutor;
    private Thread loopThread;
    private List<Cell> cells;
    private World world;
    private int numberOfRunningTimeSteps = 0;
    private int FPS = 30;
    private double averageFPS;

    public Engine(List<Cell> cells, World world) {
        this.cells = cells;
        taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        this.world = world;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        world.resetTime();
        shouldRun = true;

        long startTime;
        long estimatedTimeMillis;
        long waitTime;
        long totalTime = 0;
        long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

        int frameCount = 0;
        int maxFrameCount = 1; 

        while (shouldRun) {

            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            try {
                List<Future<Cell>> futures = taskExecutor.invokeAll(cells);
                List<Cell> futureCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

                futures.forEach((future) -> {
                    try {
                        futureCells.add(future.get());
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });

                world.setCells(futureCells);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            world.timeProceeded();

            if (numberOfRunningTimeSteps != 0 && world.getTime() == numberOfRunningTimeSteps) {
                shouldRun = false;
            }

            estimatedTimeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            waitTime = targetTime - estimatedTimeMillis;
            try {
                if (waitTime > 0.0) {
                    Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            frameCount++;
            if (frameCount == maxFrameCount) {
                averageFPS = 1000.0 / ((totalTime / frameCount) / 1000000);

                frameCount = 0;
                totalTime = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    public void start(int n) {
        loopThread = new Thread(this);
        loopThread.start();
        numberOfRunningTimeSteps = n;
    }

    public void stop() {
        shouldRun = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: You should have edited your question and put it there.